# Optimal document uploading to CloudSearch from built objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, stream, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm doing some processing on a JSON response and want to upload the resulting data to cloudsearch. I could do this one document at a time:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const JSONStream = require("JSONStream");
const jsonStream = JSONStream.parse("*");
const csd = AWS.CloudSearchDomain(config);

jsonStream.on("data", processData);

request.get(resultUrl).pipe(jsonStream);

function processData(data) {
  data = doProcessData(data);

  /*
   * `data` is now a JSON object ready to be uploaded to CloudSearch
   * e.g. {type: "add", id: "random-id", fields: {field: "a"}}
   */

  csd.uploadDocuments({contentType: "application/json", documents: [data]});
}
```

This works, but [AWS suggests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/preparing-data.html#creating-document-batches):

> To get the best possible upload performance, group add and delete operations in batches that are close to the maximum batch size

I was thinking that I could write the documents to a file and check the file size and upload the documents once the file is something like 3MB. I could get closer to 5MB but I don't want to go over the batch size:

```
/* Please ignore semantic errors */
filename = "/tmp/foo.json";
file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
file.write("[");
// in `processData`
  file.write(JSON.stringify(data));

  const stats = file.stat(filename);
  if (stats.size > 3000000) {
    file.write("]");
    csd.uploadDocuments({documents: fs.createReadStream(filename)});
    fs.trunate(filename);
  }
  else {
    file.write(",");
  }
```

This method is okay, but it would be nice to have a better way to determine if the file were ready for upload. I'd also prefer to avoid using the filesystem if I can.

I can also do this in-memory by doing something like:

```
  const stringifier = JSONStream.stringify("[", ",", "]");
  // in `processData`
    csd.uploadDocuments({documents: stringifier});
    stringifier.write(data);
```

However the batch size could go beyond 5MB. I'm also not sure how I could check how much has been written to the JSON stream.

Is there a good method for writing derived documents to CloudSearch? Failing that, is there a simple way to check how much space has been written to a stream and even how much space a variable is using?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a concept I use for downloading large files, getting the size, and the size processed. The count during a read loop will be each byte[1024] block of the stream.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
    try {
        int count;
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile(), "/");
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            if (!directory.mkdirs()) {
                throw new Exception("Could not create directory?!?!?");
            }
        }
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/ItemLocalStorage.db";
        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        int contentLength = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int byt = 0;
        int mb = 0;
        int mbLength;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            if (!isCancelled()) {
                byt += count;
                mb = ((byt/1024)/1024
                mbLength = ((contentLength / 1024) / 1024);
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        }
        if (isCancelled()) {
            output.write(0);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
        return filePath;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```